# Clarification needed for a question about norms

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have to show that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the following inequality holds:
$$ \sqrt{n} \|x\|_2 \le n \|x\|_\infty.$$
I also have the following answer:
$$\|x\|_2= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 \right)^{1/2} \le \sqrt{n} \max_{1\le i \le n} |x_i|= \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$$

Note that I understand that $\|x\|_2 \le  \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$ implies the required proof is correct, since we can multiple both sides by $\sqrt{n}$ to get it in the required form.

However, I cannot seem to grasp the rest. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : $|x_i| \le \max_k |x_k|$.

Comment: Try reading this ans - [Norm_Inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293778/1-and-2-norm-inequality)

Answer (score 2):

$\|x\|_\infty=\sup(|x_i|)$. This implies that

$\|x\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x_i^2}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\|x\|^2_\infty}=\sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: I have edited his answer, I think is a genuine typo instead of a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$ |x_i^{2}| \leq  \|x\|_{\infty}^{2}$ for each $i$. Add these up and take square root.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your comments, Tsemo made an error placing the sum outside the square root, but with the replies of Kavi and Tsemo I managed to write the following result:

$$\|x\|_2=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 \right)^{1/2} \le \left(  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \max_{1\le i \le n} |x_i| \right)^2 \right)^{1/2}= \sqrt{n} \max_{1\le i \le n} |x_i|$$

Thank you very much!